# C3.js horizontal bar chart - Highlight a specific x-axis tick together with bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highlight, c3.js

I've created a very simple horizontal bar chart with C3.js that is listing data from my SQL database.
The chart is accessible on it's own without any filter, but also by passing data from a previously visited page using $_GET.

When the user coming from a page where data is being passed to the chart, I want the chart to highlight the specific data(x-axis tick, and bar) from the previous page.

I've managed to highlight the relevant tick(which is a text) however I'm unable to highlight or add a different color to the corresponding bar.

Here is a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trent1000/3fsetng6/31/) example

[Illustration of the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfrdi.png)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    
    size: {
        height: 300,
        width: 500,
    },
     
    data: {  
    x:'x',
       columns: [
            ['nr',123,200,241,300,212,300],
            ['x','a','b','c','d','e','f'],
        ],
        type : 'bar',
        keys: {
            x: 'Name',
            value: ['nr']
        }
    },
   
    axis: {
      
        rotated: true,
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            tick: {multiline:false,}
        },
        y: {
            padding: {top:0, bottom:0},
            tick: { multiline:false, 
                    format: d3.format('s') }
        }
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5
        }
    },
    grid: {
        x: {
            show: false
        },
        y: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    legend: {show: false},
    tooltip: {
        format: {
            value: function (value, id) {
                var format = id === 'nr' ? d3.format(',') : function (d) { return  d + ' suffix'; };
                return format(value);
            }
        }
    }
});  

var highLightTick = d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick')
  .filter(function(){ 
    return d3.select(this).text() === 'd'
  })
  .style('fill', 'black')
  .style('font-size', '14px')
  .style('font-weight', 'bold');
```

How can I connect the tick and the corresponding bar so they are highlighted separately from the rest of the data?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify **highLightTick** and bind a **mouseenter** / **mouseleave** handler to every item.

See it working in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/aq9ncdtv/)

```
const highLightTick = (tick, isOn) => tick
  .style('fill', isOn ? 'black' : 'gray')
  .style('font-size', isOn ? '14px' : '12px')
  .style('font-weight', isOn ? 700 : 400);

d3.selectAll('.c3-event-rect').each(function(d, i) {
  const el = d3.select(this);
  const tick = d3.select(`.tick:nth-of-type(${i + 1})`);
  el.on('mouseenter', () => highLightTick(tick, true))
    .on('mouseleave', () => highLightTick(tick, false))
});
```

Comment: This is an effect I've wanted to achive later on however, my goal is to highlight a specific tick and it's corresponding bar together so when the user arrives to the page it is already being highlighted. That's why I used the filter function. It works well for the tick as being illustrated in my jsfiddle example, but I can't filter the bar for the tick's text term. Nonetheless I do appreciate your effort.